# The current path, customer, didn't match any of these. even when all other path runs correctly

Tags: python, django

ERROR :Using the URLconf defined in crm1.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:

```
admin/
[name='home']
products/ [name='products']
customer/<str:pk_test>/ [name='customer']
create_order/<str:pk>/ [name='create_order']
update_order/<str:pk>/ [name='update_order']
delete_order/<str:pk>/ [name='delete_order']
```

The current path, customer, didn't match any of these.
even when   i run this.....accounts/urls.py

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('',views.home, name='home'),
    path('products/',views.products, name='products'),
    path('customer/<str:pk_test>/',views.customer,name='customer'),
    path('create_order/<str:pk>/',views.createOrder,name='create_order'),
    path('update_order/<str:pk>/',views.updateOrder,name='update_order'),
    path('delete_order/<str:pk>/',views.deleteOrder,name='delete_order'),
]
```

all path are running correctly and even when i run http://127.0.0.1:8000/customer/2
it runs properly....but  when i run http://127.0.0.1:8000/customer/ error out
actually

```
/<str:pk_test>/
```

kind of path create problem i dont know

Answer (score 1):

Well there is not route for customer only. So, add this line in your `urls.py`:

```
path('customer/',views.customer,name='customer-only'),
```

*Note:- Add the line above the another code. Like:-

```
path('customer/',views.customer,name='customer-only'),
path('customer/<str:pk_test>/',views.customer,name='customer'),
```

Okay, as your `views.py` needs argument, you have to do:

```
def customer(request, pk_test=None): 
    customer=Customer.objects.get(id=pk_test) 
    orders=customer.order_set.all() 
    order_count =orders.count() 
    context={'customer':customer,'orders':orders,'order_count':order_count} 
    return render(request,'accounts/customer.html',context)
```

Comment: You can also use the same name for multiple URLs so long as the parameters are different. reverse(name, kwargs) will work out the correct one.

Comment: TypeError at /customer/
customer() missing 1 required positional argument: 'pk_test'...would not resolve issue to @biplove

Comment: @Andee Thank you for your suggestion, But I wanted it to make it simple and inside the area of question. But, again thank you for your suggestions.

Comment: @Andee i m new to django if possible give me some examples

Comment: @SumitSikri I have edited the answer. It should work now.

Comment: @BiploveLamichhane   TypeError at /customer/
customer() missing 1 required positional argument: 'pk_test'

Comment: Did you made the changes, first only customer, then customer with arguments. ????

Comment: def customer(request, pk_test):
 customer=Customer.objects.get(id=pk_test)

 orders=customer.order_set.all()
 order_count =orders.count()

 context={'customer':customer,'orders':orders,'order_count':order_count}
 return render(request,'accounts/customer.html',context)

Comment: hey bro i have pasted the code plz check...error is still out

Comment: Now change your views.py as I did. But, now your error should be different. Let me know the traceback now. then I ll explain what happened.

Comment: Change your customer function in views.py

Comment: TypeError at /customer/
customer_ch() missing 1 required positional argument: 'pk_test'
@BiploveLamichhane